# Javascript accessing object and array defined in modular function

Tags: scope, javascript

This is a bit foreign to me and I'm probably not understanding it correctly.  This is what I have:

```
var imgModule = (function() {
    var imgLocations = {};
    var images = [];
    imgLocations.setImage = function(img, location) {
        imgLocations[img] = location;
    }
    imgLocations.getImg = function(img) {
        return imgLocations[img];
    }
    imgLocations.setImageArray = function(img) {
        images.push(img);
    }
    imgLocations.getImageArray = function() {
        return images;
    }
    return imgLocations;
}());
```

I want to be able to access the imgLocations Object and images array from outside this function.  The setting functions work, but

```
document.getElementById("but").onclick = function() {
    console.log(imgModule.imgLocations.getImageArray());
    console.log(imgModule.imgLocations.getImg(imgName));
}
```

Both return "undefined".  How do I access these variables?  And how can I improve this function?  Please be patient with me and explain what I'm doing wrong :)  I'm trying to learn it the right way instead of defining a global variable outside all functions.

Comment: Yay! three answers, 3 seconds away from each other hahaha Essentially the same answer so... votes for you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working, is because your `imgModule` is returning the `imgLocations` object. That being the case, `imgModule` will actually be the `imgLocations` object. So you would access your methods like so:

```
imgModule.setImage()
imgModule.getImg()
imgModule.getImageArray()
imgModule.setImageArray()
```

And as @gillesc stated. If you are wanting to keep the current syntax of `imgModule.imgLocations.getImg()` then you could return the `imgLocations` like so

```
return {
    imgLocations: imgLocations
}
```

doing so would allow you to add more functionality to your module

```
return {
    imgLocations: imgLocations,
    otherObject: otherObject
}
...
imgModule.otherObject.someFunctionCall();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Is there a way to call the object and array without using "imgLocations" and "otherObject"?  Or do they have to be a part of a function which will return the object and array?

Comment: If I understand correctly. no. You could attached the methods directly to `imgModule`. You would write it like so: `this.setImage = function(){}`, then you wouldn't need to return anything

Comment: So if I wanted to clear the object or the array, I would have to write a function for both of those? There's no way to write "imgModule.imgLocations={}"?

Comment: If you assigned the `imgLocations` to the imgModule like so you could do it. `this.imgLocations`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are returning the object created and are not setting it as a property of an object.

So in your case this is how it would work.

```
document.getElementById("but").onclick = function() {
    console.log(imgModule.getImageArray());
    console.log(imgModule.getImg(imgName));
}
```

What you need to do is return it like this

```
return {
    imgLocations: imgLocations
}
```

If you want the API you are attending to create and still have access to the array which you can not do currently.

Answer (score 1):

You don't access imgModule.imgLocations, since what you return is imgLocations, you should access them as:

```
document.getElementById("but").onclick = function() {
    console.log(imgModule.getImageArray());
    console.log(imgModule.getImg(imgName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to write module pattern.
For deep understanding, I recommend you following article:
[The Module Pattern, by Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)

and pay attention to example with counter:

```
var testModule = (function () {

  var counter = 0;

  return {

    incrementCounter: function () {
      return counter++;
    },

    resetCounter: function () {
      console.log( "counter value prior to reset: " + counter );
      counter = 0;
    }
  };

})();

// Usage:

// Increment our counter
testModule.incrementCounter();

// Check the counter value and reset
// Outputs: counter value prior to reset: 1
testModule.resetCounter();
```

Comment: While that link may provide an answer to the question, you should include the relevant parts of the solution in your answer. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page is changed or removed.

Comment: @JWLim your truth. Updated information above. Thank's.